Need help with identifying a SMD part
Can anyone please help in identifying this SMD part marked with "CP6W"?

This is part of the power supply of a 8 inch tablet from China, "Chuwi Hi8 pro".
My findings as of now are:

The coil is connected between pins 4 and 5
Pin 2 is GND
Other connections cannot be determined since I get 0 Ohms on all other pins to GND, except pin 3
I could not find the connection where pin 3 goes to

I have an older version of this tablet (not "pro") where I can read "LPS 5V5u5" on the chip at a similar position in the motherboard, so I suppose, the chip in question might be a step-up converter, too.
The tablet started to get hot when operated. Later (some weeks) it drained the battery completely, so no charging over the USB-C port could be achieved.
After opening the tablet I managed to add an external Li-Ion charger in parallel to the battery and so could measure a stand by current of around 500 mA, tablet switched OFF.
With the external charger attached, the tablet works as normal, but it gets very hot. I guess, the chip in question is short-circuited and leads the power through, unregulated.
The chip and the coil are burning hot.
I suppose, this IC is defective and I want to find a replacement type to get the tablet back to operation.
Hoping, someone can help...
Thanks!
Harry

It's a ETA Solutions ETA1036V50S2F DC-DC converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)
